# delete from BST in C

Tags: c, binary-search-tree, free

I'm trying to create the delete function in a BST.
When I try to delete the pointer I get this error.
[Click to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42K5L.png)

```
void delete(Node** root, int data) {
    if((*root) == NULL)
        return;
    else if(data < (*root)->data)
        delete(&(*root)->left, data);
    else if(data > (*root)->data)
        delete(&(*root)->right, data);
    else {
        printf("%d\n", (*root)->data);
        // case 1
        if((*root)->left == NULL && (*root)->right == NULL) {
            free((*root));
            printf("wssal");
        }
    }

}
```

[Problem view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42K5L.png)

```
 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/42K5L.png
```

Comment: You say, "this error" but don't describe any error.

Comment: click on the link "Problem view"

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And it's not good form to post a link to an external image. Just paste the output as text into the question with a description.

Comment: Try compiling with `-Wall -Wextra` to see if any additional errors pop up during compilation.  Also try using a debugger such as `GDB` or a memory debugger such as `valgrind` to determine where exactly the error is occurring.

Comment: The link shows a bunch of numbers that don't appear to be a problem or error. It is also not clear how the code above could generate that output.

Comment: What do you think `delete(&(*root)->left, data);` does exactly?

Comment: to find the target node

Answer (score 1):

Your `delete` function doesn't update the tree structure to reflect the fact that the removed node is no longer in the tree. So you are leaving the tree including pointers to a node that no longer exists.

Comment: Perfect, can i get the parent of the target node to delete , so i can delete the left pointer or te right ?

Comment: @XPRO You can get it by walking the tree again. Or you can get it by including in each node a pointer to its parent. You can get it by keeping track of it while you traverse.